# All addons are disabled

Tags: add-on, customization

I just tried to install Node Wrangler. When I went to enable it, the box was greyed out. But not only the new Node Wrangler addon, ALL of them! Every single addon is greyed out so that I cannot click the checkbox to enable them. How can I fix this and enable my addons?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. Turns out, it was just a huge oversight on my part. I had simply neglected to actually CLICK the checkboxes. All plugins are functioning normally